# Cannot merge two vertices

Tags: vertices

I have a mesh containing only edges, that was converted from curves. The net is split into small chunks - a couple of edges each. You can see it by selecting one vert/edge and CTRL+L - they are not all linked. I want them to be linked, so I would merge close vertices but I can't!
I select everything in edit mode and can't find Merge option under Vertex Menu. Why?

Here's my blend:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yqlNcy1yvCZS4lQE6frFc5dFmzQ16ttX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Merge is under Mesh menu, or alt M, you can merge but you'll need a high value as your object is rather big

Comment: True, my mistake.